# Comparing group of people/countries on multiple binary variables

Tags: categorical-data, multivariate-analysis

I have a large amount of data from three countries on work values. People are given 17 work value items (good pay, working with pleasant people, job security etc.) and asked the ones that they find important. The ones that they find important are coded with 1 and the ones that are not mentioned re coded with 0.

Now, I want to classify these work values into three types: intrinsic (8 work values), extrinsic (6 ww), social (4ww). Then I would like to see how they look in each country and most importantly, I would like to make comparisons among the countries.

I am thinking of computing the items and doing a chi-square testing, but I don't feel confident about this solution. What do you think? Am I totally wrong? Do you have any other suggestions?

I would appreciate if you could share your views on this.

Comment: I would look into multiple correspondence analysis, at least as a start.